# C++11's "default" can be only applied on special member functions?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, default, member

Does `=default` only apply to special member functions? I tried the following and it did not compile:

```
struct A{
   A(int, char)=default;
   int i;
   char c;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can only explicitly default special member functions. From [dcl.fct.def.default]:

> A function that is explicitly defaulted shall
>   (1.1) — be a special member function,

After all, only special member functions are *implicitly* defaulted - so why would it make sense to *explicitly* default anything else?

In this case, you can simply remove the constructor and make `A` an aggregate. This will allow you to use list-initialization (`A a{42, 'c'};`).